# Solr 7.x "/export" response handler not working with Streaming Expressions

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am doing a Solr streaming expression, and I try to use the `/export` handler to fetch all of the results. Consider the following query:

```
search(main, q=*:*, fl="SSRN",qt="/export",sort="SSRN asc")
```

I configured my `schema.xml` for the `SSRN` field as follows:

```
<field name="SSRN" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" docValues="true" />
```

Since the SSRN field is a docValue, it should work. The results are just the standard 10 documents. This is running in a SolrCloud environment with just one node and one shard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What endpoint are you querying? What does your actual query URL look like? What is `int` defined as?

Comment: I tried both in the HTTP endpoint and in the streaming page. For the streaming page, I ran the same query as in the post. `int` is defined as `<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It seems that in `SOLR-8426: Enable /export, /stream and /sql handlers by default and remove them from example configs`, they removed the need to add `/export` handler to the `solrconfig.xml`. If you do add it, then it doesn't work. The solution is just to remove this code (from `solrconfig.xml`):

```
<requestHandler name="/export" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
  <str name="rq">{!xport}</str>
  <str name="wt">xsort</str>
  <str name="distrib">false</str>
  <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```